# Expectation over Poisson distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I ran into a problem calculating the following expectation value:

```
smin = -6.; ds = 0.1; c = 6;
Expectation[x/c*e^((smin + (counter - 1)*ds)*x/c), x ≈ PoissonDistribution[c]]
```

It seems that *Mathematica* gets stuck for the value `counter = 10`, and I don't understand why. Could someone help?

Comment: I can get the generic `Expectation[x/c Exp[a + b x /c], 
 x \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[n]]`.

Comment: How is that possible? On my laptop it doesn't work!

Comment: Is it possible that you need `\[Distributed]` instead of `≈` ? (as @b.gatessucks suggests).  Using that works for me on both versions 11.01 and 10.4.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: I don't think so, with Normal distribution works with ≈

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(*  "11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)"  *)

smin = -6; ds = 1/10; c = 6; counter = 10;
```

As a workaround, you can either use [`NExpectation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NExpectation.html)

```
NExpectation[x/c*E^((smin + (counter - 1)*ds)*x/c), 
 x \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[c]]

(*  0.0137666  *)
```

Or take the [`Mean`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) of the [`TransformedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html)

```
Mean@TransformedDistribution[x/c*E^((smin + (counter - 1)*ds)*x/c), 
  x \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[c]]

(*  E^(-(137/20) + 6/E^(17/20))  *)

% // N

(*  0.0137666  *)
```

**EDIT:** Works on an earlier version

```
$Version

(*  "10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"  *)

smin = -6; ds = 1/10; c = 6; counter = 10;

Expectation[x/c*E^((smin + (counter - 1)*ds)*x/c), 
 x \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[c]]

(*  E^(-(137/20) + 6/E^(17/20))  *)

% // N

(*  0.0137666  *)
```

Comment: I just tried with NExpectation and I get the same problem. Now I try with the second method you proposed. Thanks

Comment: @FrancescoCoghi - what version and OS are you using?

Comment: I'm on windows10 with Mathematica 10.4